# Strings not getting translated with googletrans API

Tags: python, google-translation-api, googletrans

can someone help me please? I have a df column with around 2.6K entries and its translating only half of them.

I looked at the raw file and there is no difference between the strings that are translated vs those that aren't!

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator(service_urls=[
      'translate.google.com',
      'translate.google.co.kr',
    ])

i, results = 0, []
for feedback in df["open_feedback"]:
    try:
        language = translator.detect(feedback).lang
        res = translator.translate(feedback, src=language, dest='en').text
        #print(res)
        results.append(res)
    except Exception:
        print(feedback)
        results.append(None)
        i += 1

print("Total failed cases: ", i)
```

Comment: Could it be an API restriction? Public APIs usually have a rate limit to prevent hammering it, which looks like it could be the case here. I would recommend catching the exception correctly (`catch Exception as e`) and logging it.

Comment: As an aside, why use a loop and append everything to a list, instead of just using `apply()` ?